# Second Element of a List

Tags: scala, list

From the Book programming in Scala I got the following line of code:

```
val second: List[ Int] => Int = { case x :: y :: _ => y }
//warning: match may not be exhaustive.
```

It states that this function will return the second element of a list of integers if the list is not empty or nil. Stil this part is a bit awkward to me:

```
case x :: y :: _
```

How does this ecxactly work? Does this mathches any list with at least 2 Elements and than return the second? If so can somebody still explain the syntax? I understood that :: is invoked on the right operand. So it could be written as

```
(_.::(y)).::(X)
```

Still I than don't get why this would return 2

```
val second: List[ Int] => Int = { case x :: y :: _ => y }
var x = List(1,2)
second(x) //returns 2
```

Comment: besides the answers below I'd recommend reading this:
http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html
It deals with extractors / unapply and how they relate to patternmatching. it's a bit dated but is still correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the structure of list in scala its `head::tail`, first element is treated as head and all remaining ones as tail(Nil will be the last element of tail). whenever you do x::y::_, x will match the head of the list and remaining will be tail and again y will match the head of the next list(tail of first list)

eg:

```
val l = List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

you can see this list in differnt ways:

```
1::2::3::4::5::Nil
1::List(2,3,4,5)
1::2::List(2,3,4,5)
```

and so on

So try matching the pattern. In your question y will give the second element

Answer (score 2):

In the REPL, you can type:

```
scala> val list = "a" :: "b" :: Nil 
list: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

which is to be read from right to left, and means take the end of a List (Nil), prepend String "b" and to this List ("b" :: Nil) prepend String a,  a :: ("b" :: Nil) but you don't need the parens, so it can be written  "a" :: "b" :: Nil.

In pattern matching you will more often see:

```
... list match {
  case Nil => // ... 
  case x :: xs => // ...
}
```

to distinguish between empty list, and nonempty, where xs might be a rest of list, but matches Nil too, if the whole list is ("b" :: Nil) for example, then x="b" and xs=Nil.

But if list= "a" :: "b" :: Nil, then x="a" and xs=(b :: Nil).

In your example, the deconstruction is just one more step, and instead of a name like xs, the joker sign _ is used, indicating, that the name is probably not used and doesn't play a role.

Answer (score 1):

The value `second` is of function type, it takes `List[Int]` and returns `Int`.

If the list has first element ("x"), and a second element ("y"), and whatever comes next (we don't care about it), we simply return the element "y" (which is the second element of the list).

In any other case, the function is not defined. You can check that:

```
scala> val second: PartialFunction[List[Int], Int] = {
     |     case x :: y :: _ => y
     |   }
second: PartialFunction[List[Int],Int] = <function1>

scala> second.isDefinedAt(List(1,2,3))
res18: Boolean = true

scala> second.isDefinedAt(List(1,2))
res19: Boolean = true

scala> second.isDefinedAt(List(0))
res20: Boolean = false
```

Comment: `x` could be `_`.

Comment: @Jubobs Correct.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. When you think about pattern matching you should think about matching a structure.

The first part of the `case` statement describes a structure. This structure may describe one or more things (variables) which are useful to deriving your result.

In your example, you are interested in deriving the second element of a list. A shorthand to build a list in Scala is to use `::` method (also called *cons*). `::` can also be used to describe a structure in `case` statement. **At this time, you shouldn't think about evaluation of the `::` method in first part of `case`**. May be that's why you are saying about evaluation of `_.::(y).::(x)`. The `::` cons operator help us describe the structure of the list in terms of its elements. In this case, the first element (`x`) , the second element (`y`) and the rest of it (`_` wildcard). We are interested in a structure that is a list with at least 2 elements and the third can be anything - a Nil to indicate end of list or another element - hence the wildcard.

The second part of the case statement, uses the second element to derive the result (`y`).

**More on List and Consing**

List in Scala is similar to a `LinkedList`. You know about the first element called `head` and start of the rest of the list. When traversing the linked list you stop if the rest of the list is `Nil`. This `::` cons operator helps us visualise the structure of the linked list. Although Scala compile would actually be calling `::` methods evaluating from right to left as you described `_.::(y).::(x)`

As an aside, you might have already noticed that the Scala compiler might be complain that your match isn't exhaustive. This means that this `second` method would work for list of any size. Because there isn't any `case` statement to describe list with zero or one element. Also, as mentioned in comments of previous answers, if you aren't interested in first element you can describe it as a wildcard `_`.

`case _ :: y :: _ => y`

I hope this helped.

Comment: Really great explanation! Thanks for taking the time to writing this down in such a concise way.

Comment: Thanks @HansHerrlich